# ag-Grid: All rows in edit mode when loaded

Tags: ag-grid

I have `ag-grid` which is `editable`.

I want all rows in edit mode by default when grid is loaded. I know that `ag-grid` doesn't support this feature. But would like to know that whether there is any way to achieve this ?

I have all type of columns in my grid, `text`, `select`, `customCellEditor`